# QuickAction button not visible for a user profile

Tags: permissions, page-layout, access

I created a custom quickAction on Case object and placed it on a Case page layout(lets call it testLayout).

For that case record type and a user profile (let's call it xyz), that page layout testLayout has been assigned.

When i login as a user with profile xyz, i am unable to see the quickAction button. I see it when i login as a system administtrator, but not as a user of profile xyz.

Is there some sort of permission or access that needs to be assigned to a quickAction button?

Comment: I think try giving the profile delete permissions to Case and see if the user is still unable to see the button on his Page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the type of quick action, this could be one of a few things.

1. If it's a Visualforce quick action, make sure that the xyz profile has access to the associated VF page, and if the VF page uses a standard controller, make sure that the xyz profile has access to that object.
2. If it's a "Create a Record" or "Update a Record" quick action, make sure that the xyz profile has CRUD to create or edit the child object record.
3. If the quick action is associated with a specific record type, make sure that the xyz profile has access to the record type.